# How many elements set $\{\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{n})| k \in \mathbb Z\}$ has, $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

How many elements set $\{\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{n})| k \in \mathbb Z\}$ has if $n \in \mathbb N$.

**My attempt**

The idea is to split $\mathbb Z$ in $m\in \mathbb N$ disjunctive subsets $U_i$, such that $\forall k \in U_i, \forall l \in U_j, \cos(\frac{2\pi k}{n})\ne \cos(\frac{2\pi l}{n})$ if $j\ne i$ and $\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{n})= \cos(\frac{2\pi l}{n})$ if $j = i$. Then $m$ is the number of elements in my set.

Next I reason that $$\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{n})- \cos(\frac{2\pi l}{n})=2\sin(\frac{\pi (k-l)}{n})\sin(\frac{\pi (k+l)}{n})=0 \iff k + l = n z \lor k - l = n z, z \in \mathbb Z$$

Now I consider relation $R$ on $\mathbb Z$

$$ (k,l) \in R :\iff k + l = n z \lor k - l = n z, z \in \mathbb Z$$

This relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, so it is an equivalence relation and its equivalence classes are exactly the subsets I am looking for.

I note that $[k]=\{l \in \mathbb Z : k + l = n z \lor k - l = n z, z \in \mathbb Z\}=(-k+n \mathbb Z)\bigcup(k+n \mathbb Z)$.

So we can define a surjective function $f: \{k+n \mathbb Z : k \in \mathbb Z\} \to \{[k]:k\in \mathbb Z\} , (k+n \mathbb Z) \mapsto (-k+n \mathbb Z)\bigcup(k+n \mathbb Z)$

Because $\{k+n \mathbb Z : k \in \mathbb Z\}$ has $n$ elements and $f$ is surjective, then I have at most $n$ equivalence classes $[k]$. We denote elements of $\{k+n \mathbb Z : k \in \mathbb Z\}$ as $\overline{0},...,\overline{n-1}$.

Take $\overline{k_1},\overline{k_2}$ from $\{k+n \mathbb Z : k \in \mathbb Z\}$, then

$$f(\overline{k_1})=f(\overline{k_2}) \iff (-k_1+n \mathbb Z)\bigcup(k_1+n \mathbb Z) = (-k_2+n \mathbb Z)\bigcup(k_2+n \mathbb Z)$$

Because $(k_1+n \mathbb Z)\bigcap(k_2+n \mathbb Z)=\emptyset$ and $(-k_1+n \mathbb Z)\bigcap(-k_2+n \mathbb Z)=\emptyset$ it follows that:

$$(-k_1+n \mathbb Z)\bigcup(k_1+n \mathbb Z)=(-k_2+n \mathbb Z)\bigcup(k_2+n \mathbb Z) \iff ( x \in (k_1+n \mathbb Z) \iff x \in (-k_2+n \mathbb Z) ) \land ( x \in (k_2+n \mathbb Z) \iff x \in (-k_1+n \mathbb Z) ) \iff \overline{k_1} = -\overline{k_2} \iff \overline{k_1} = \overline{n-k_2} $$

So $f(\overline{k_1})=f(\overline{k_2}) \iff \overline{k_1}=\overline{n-k_2}$.

Now I go through elements $\overline{0},...,\overline{n-1}$ and try to find for each $\overline{k_1}$ a $\overline{k_2}$ such that $\overline{k_1}=\overline{n-k_2}$. Clearly $\overline{0}$ can not be paired, and whether all elements in $\overline{1},...,\overline{n-1}$ can be paired depends on whether $n$ is even or odd.

Thus if $n$ is odd, then there are $\frac{n+1}{2}$ equivalence classes (and elements in my set), and if $n$ is even, then $\frac{n}{2}+1$ equivalence classes (and elements in my set).

Comment: @Sergey What? You have $n$ evenly spaced points on the unit circle. Clearly setting $k=0$ is the same as $k=n,2n$ etc. So it has at most $n$ members. Don't you just have to separate out the remaining members that are identical basically by easy $\cos$ identities?

Comment: @Rubertos I think you imply that $cos(x)=cos(y) \iff x-y = 2 \pi k, k \in \mathbb Z$, and that is wrong.

Comment: @SergeyZykov You are right. I was unconscious of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $k$ only influences the cosine modulo $n$. If you replace $k$ by $k+Mn$, i.e. shift it by a multiple of $n$ where $M$ is any integer, the cosine is the same.

For this reason, it's enough to count the number of values of the cosines for $k=0,1,2,\dots n-1$. Or, let's shift the interval to integers such that 
$$ -\frac{n}{2} \lt k \leq \frac n2$$
so that one period is covered. The cosine is an even function so $k\to -k$ doesn't change the cosine, either. That's why it's enough to count the number of the values of cosines for the integer values of $k$ such that
$$0\leq k \leq \frac{n}{2}$$
For an even $k$, the number of values is $1+n/2$, from zero to $n/2$. For an odd $k$, it is $(1+n)/2$, from zero to $(n-1)/2$. So we may unify it as $1+{\rm floor}(n/2)$ where "floor" is the largest integer not larger than the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The cosine is periodic with period $2\pi.$ This implies that every equivalence class has a least one representative in $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ so you can limit your search for equivalences to that set.

The cosine is also bijective on $[0,+\pi]$ so the only possibility of having nontrivial equivalence classes in $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ is when $k+l=n.$ That should help you count the classes. You may need to distinguish cases according to the remainder of $n$ after division by 2.

Comment: No, I think that there is no "modulo 4" problem here, just "modulo 2". You could get to "modulo 4" if there were an absolute value of the cosine or something like that.

Comment: I am referring to the same distinction that you solved using the "floor" function.

Comment: I am just saying - here and there - that you only need to distinguish according to the remainder of $n$ after division by $2$, i.e. whether $n$ is even or odd, not division by $4$.

Comment: You are right, I will adapt my answer.